# exceeded maximum number of wifi locks android

Tags: android, dictionary, wifi, latitude-longitude

I am sending `latitude` and `longitude` every 5 min to server at the time i am acquiring `WakeLock` and `WifiLock` but getting error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Exceeded maximum number of wifi locks
at android.net.wifi.WifiManager$WifiLock.acquire(WifiManager.java:1622)
```

code of snippet is,

```
public class WakeLocker {
    private WakeLock wl_cpu;
    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private WifiLock wifiLock = null;

    @SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "Wakelock" })
    public void acquire(Context ctx) {
        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF,
                "MyWifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();

        wl_cpu = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyCpuLock");
        wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
    }

    public void release() {

        if ((wifiLock != null) || (wifiLock.isHeld() == true)) {
            wifiLock.release();
            wifiLock = null;
        }
        if ((wl_cpu != null) || (wl_cpu.isHeld() == true)) {
            wl_cpu.release();
            wl_cpu = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Not getting any solution. Please any suggestion.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you figured this out but how often are you calling your acquire/release function. Can't really help figure out whats going on, with some of your main code to see how the wakelocker class is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Acquire `wake lock` when it is not held. Replace all `wifiLock.acquire()` with
`if (!wifiLock.held()) wifiLock.acquire()`

Answer (score -2):

I just surrounded with try-catch.